# Вывести 2 переменные

Tags: php

Доброго всем времени суток. Тут такой простецкий вопрос возник по выводу двух переменных в php
например:

```
$val1 = "1";
$val2 = "2";
$val3 = $val1 $val2  -- вот как это правильно записать? нужно чтобы $val3 = 1 2 получилось в итоге
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$val3 = $val1.' '.$val2
```

Comment: лишь добавлю.

так еще

            $val3 = "$val1 $val2";

Разница между одинарной кавычкой и двойной в том что одинарная не поддерживает переменные и выведет просто как текст переменные, а двойная наоборот.

если непонятно и/или интересно поэкспериментируйте.

Comment: @M11, тогда уже лучше так:  

    $val3 = "{$val1} {$val2}";

Comment: @VenZell чем лучше ? такая запись оправдана только в сложных случаях.

Comment: Отделением переменной от текста. Лучше приучать себя заранее. :)

Comment: да ладно, любой редактор с подсветкой нормально обработает просто `$`

Comment: Я вот о чем:  

    $name = "John";
    echo "$namey";   //пусто
    echo "{$name}y"; //Johny

Comment: ну так да, хотя по количеству символов:

    $ echo -n 'echo "{$name}y";'|wc -c
    16
    $ echo -n 'echo $name."y";'|wc -c
    15

успокаивает одно:

    $ echo -n 'echo "The".$name."y";'|wc -c
    21
    $ echo -n 'echo "The{$name}y";'|wc -c
    19